# Check if Multiple WebViews have finished Load

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am currently using NSNotificationCentre to pass the WebViewStart and WebViewFinish events for 5 WebViews.

Inside the WebViewStart method I start the animation of a progress bar.
Inside the WebViewFinish method I stop the animation of a progress bar.

Obviously the problem is that if 5 WebViews are loading, and one WebView finishes loading, it fires the WebViewFinish method and stops the animation, even though the other WebViews are still loading.

Is there any way to check something like the following?

```
- (void)_webViewProgressFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([webView1 & webView2 & webView3 finishedLoading]) {
        [_loadingIndicator stopAnimation:self];
    }
}
```

The code I have at the moment doesn't seem appropriate for the number of WebViews I have. The code I am using at the moment and having problems with is as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_mainWebView];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_mainWebView];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_subWebView1];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_subWebView1];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_subWebView2];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_subWebView2];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_subWebView3];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_subWebView3];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_subWebView4];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_subWebView4];
}

- (void)_webViewProgressStarted:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [_loadingIndicator startAnimation:self];
}

- (void)_webViewProgressFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [_loadingIndicator stopAnimation:self];
}
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance everyone!

**EDIT: I ended up finding the solution myself. May not be the most elegant, but nevertheless:**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{ 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_mainWebView];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_mainWebView];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_subWebView1];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_subWebView1];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_subWebView2];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_subWebView2];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_subWebView3];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_subWebView3];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressStarted:) name:WebViewProgressStartedNotification object:_subWebView4];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:_subWebView4];
}

- (void)_webViewProgressStarted:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([_mainWebView isEqual:[notification object]]) {
        [_mainWebViewProgress startAnimation:self];
    } else if ([_subWebView1 isEqual:[notification object]]) {
         [_subView1Progress startAnimation:self];       
    } else if ([_subWebView2 isEqual:[notification object]]) {
     [_subView2Progress startAnimation:self];   
    } else if ([_subWebView3 isEqual:[notification object]]) {
         [_subView3Progress startAnimation:self];   
    } else if ([_subWebView4 isEqual:[notification object]]) {
         [_subView4Progress startAnimation:self];   
    }
}
```

What this does is gets the notification object, which is an ID, and compares it to our WebViews. If they are the same, then that WebView has started/finished load.

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: With your notification registration, you can pass `nil` as the `object` parameter and you'll receive notifications from all objects that post that particular notification. Doing that will reduce your lines of code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` to two instead of ten.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate notification for each of the 5 web views. Create 5 boolean values that can be set to true as each web view is finished. When a web view finishes, have the notification center post it's notification. The method that receives this notification should first set it's boolean value to true saying that it finished. Then check to see if all 5 boolean values are set to true. If yes, stop the activity indicator. If no, leave it spinning.

Comment: i was thinking something similar to this. The problem I have with this method is simple, I don't know how to retrieve from the method 'WebViewFinishProgress' the name of the WebView, so how do I know which WebView has finished loading? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Try doing a simple compare inside the webViewDidFinishLoad: method. The delegate method is provided with the calling UIWebView for reference. It's passed in by default as "webView" unless you've overridden it to some other name. Therefore you should be able to just test like so: `if (webView = myOtherWebViewObject) {execute this code;}`

Comment: Just to clarify this isn't for iOS it's mac. How would I go about comparing? Thanks again

Comment: I was thinking in iOS, not Cocoa. My apologies on not reading the tags clearly. I'll see if I can implement something similar and let you know the results. iOS has an object method you can call "isEqual" which will compare two objects. Can you use the same method to test in Mac? `if ([webView isEqual:otherView])` ?

Comment: No problem, and thanks. I don't understand why you'd want to compare 2 webViews?

Answer (score 0):

You could just count until you get 5 notifications. you could also estimate progress as the views finish one at a time, Nx20% for the aggregate in percentage.